# How to make an update interface which gets called in main update

Tags: c#

Interface:

```
public interface IonStateLoadUpdate
{
    void onStateLoadUpdate();
}
```

Class 1:

```
class foo
{
    private void onLoadUpdate()
    {
       // How to call interface onStateLoadUpdate here ?
    }
}
```

Class 2 which inherits IonStateLoadUpdate

```
class poo: IonStateLoadUpdate
{
     public void onStateLoadUpdate()
     {
         // This should get call once foo calls onLoadUpdate
     }
}
```

Comment: you would need an object of this interface inside the method in `foo`. like `IonStateLoadUpdate obj = new poo();`

Comment: What if we have +10 classes which are inherit this interface, do we need to create new obj for all in foo ? I want onStateLoadUpdate to only get update in load state update which is  onLoadUpdate()

Comment: this was merely 1 example. You don't inherit an interface you implement it. each class makes its own implementation. the good point in that is that you can exchange them. So this is exactly the point you need to think about. How do you intend to pass those different objects into your method! via a parameter? or via a class variable like in the strategy pattern?=!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
class foo
{
    private void onLoadUpdate(IonStateLoadUpdate x)
    {
       IonStateLoadUpdate.onStateLoadUpdate();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var p = new poo();
...
...
var f = new foo();
f.onLoadUpdate(p);
```